# Swagger 2.0 deserialization of $ref properties

Tags: .net, swagger, nswag

I'm currently updating a .net 2.1 API to .net core 6. Just about got it all done except that the angular client of this API is having issues with the naming of the classes when generated using NSwag. (I can not change the Angular App.)
The original API produced the following Swagger 2.0 Json file (just a part of the file)...

```
"CloseJobResponse": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "status": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "promptType": {
      "enum": [ "DowntimeAcknowledgement", "QuantityAcknowledgement", "OpenQAAcknowledgement", "WasteAnalysisAcknowledgement" ],
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

and NSwag created the class with the "promptType" property named promptType of type... **CloseJobResponsePromptType**

However in the .net 6 API (with options.SerializeAsV2=true;) produces the following json...

```
"CloseJobPromptType": {
      "enum": ["DowntimeAcknowledgement","QuantityAcknowledgement","OpenQAAcknowledgement","WasteAnalysisAcknowledgement"],
      "type": "string"
    }

"CloseJobResponse": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "status": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "promptType": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/CloseJobPromptType"
        }
      }
    }
```

and NSwag created the class with the "promptType" property named promptType of type... **CloseJobPromptType**

The question is how do I get the .net 6 API to serialize the promptType property like the .net 2.1 API did? (or change the class name of the **CloseJobPromptType** to **CloseJobResponsePromptType**)

I've manually change the .nt 6 Json file to the .net 2.1 style and NSwag creates the classes and names as the .net 2.1.

I can not change the Angular App.

My current swagger def is...

```
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{   
    options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Version = "v1",
        Title = "Integrations API",
        Description = "Integrations API",
    });  
});

app.UseSwagger(options =>
{
    options.SerializeAsV2=true;
});
```